# Create and Access .db file in android 11 without MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, kotlin, storage, mediastore

I tried a lot but not able to create .db file in android storage, path is Document->AppFolder->DatabaseFile.db using media store

Below code is create file but not with .db extension

```
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "/databaseFile");
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/vnd.sqlite3");
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/AppFolder/");

Uri uri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), values);
                   if (uri != null) {
                       OutputStream outputStream = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
                       if (outputStream != null) {
                           outputStream.write("This is menu category data.".getBytes());
                           outputStream.close();
                       }
                   }
```

And also that file is not accessible after reinstalled.

````
String selection = MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH + "=?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/AppFolder/"};
String column = MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA;

Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, new String[]{column,"_display_name"}, selection, selectionArgs, null);
           
           if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
               while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                   String nameColumn = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
               }
           }```
````

Comment: `path is Document->AppFolder->DatabaseFile.db using media store` ??? I have no idea which path that would be. Please tell full path.

Comment: `but not with .db extension` Well change `"/databaseFile"` to `"databaseFile.db"`.

Comment: `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/AppFolder/"` Change to `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/AppFolder"`.

Comment: `And also that file is not accessible after reinstalled.` Accessable or not listed by cursor?

Comment: @blackapps,
And also that file is not accessible after reinstalled. Accessable or not listed by cursor?

Yes those file is exists but not listed by cursor.

Comment: "And also that file is not accessible after reinstalled" -- use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument` and let the user decide where on the user's device (or the user's cloud storage) the user wants  you to put the backup. Your fresh installation can then use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument` and let the user pick which backup to restore. See [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Room/pages/chap-backup-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Room) for samples.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use the Room library from Google.
Easy and no access required.
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room